# При сжатии файлов средствами Windows на диске хранится и сжатая и обычная версии одновременно

Tags: ssd, сжатие

Купил жёский диск на 4TB. Сейчас он заполнился до предела:

[image: заполненый лиск]

При этом на самом диске всего 1.2TB данных.

[image: забитый диск]

Я использую файлы со сжатием, но они, видимо, хранятся и в сжатом и в обычном виде одновременно и забивают весь диск! Кто знает, как это можно пофиксить?

Comment: "Видимо"? с чего такой вывод?

Comment: С того, что в свойствах файлов сумма их полных размеров и сжатых размеров равна объёму диска.

Comment: Папка comb весит 1,29 Тб. Остальное место занимают другие папки. Нэ?

Comment: Исходя из картинок не очевидно. На диске они занимают ~40%. (это упакованный объем) Посмотрите, может у Вас скрытые папки есть? Возьмите, например FAR Manager и с его помощью подсчитайте объем Ваших папок. Всех видимых. Может файл подкачки или что-нибудь другое скрытое есть.

Comment: 1,2 Тб это в одной папке, а не на всем диске.

Comment: Во-первых эта папка единственная, я же не дебил.

Comment: Во-вторых скрытых файлов нет

Comment: В-третьих это был сбой, он пофиксился командой chkdsk D: /F